# What is the difference between the bitcoind command line options "addnode" and "connect"?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, p2p, peer-discovery

As seen here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Command-line_arguments

> -addnode=ip          Add a node to connect to and attempt to keep the connection open
>   -connect=ip          Connect only to the specified node(s)

Both of those explanations seem to say the same thing to me.

Can anyone explain them in more detail?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`addnode` add a node to the list of nodes to connect.
`connect` only connect to THIS node.

For example, if you are currently connected to the nodes `{A, B, C}` and then issue…

`addnode=D`: you'll be connected to `{A, B, C, D}`
`connect=D`: you'll be connected to `{D}`

Answer (score 1):

Some additional guidance is in [share/examples/bitcoin.conf](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/share/examples/bitcoin.conf) to add to Nontenda's answer.

> Let's say for instance you use `addnode=4.2.2.4`, `addnode` will connect
> you to and tell you about the nodes connected to `4.2.2.4`.  In addition
> it will tell the other nodes connected to it that you exist so they
> can connect to you.
>
> `connect` will not do the above when you "connect" to it. It will **only**
> connect you to `4.2.2.4` and no one else. So if you're behind a
> firewall, or have other problems finding nodes, add some using
> `addnode`. If you want to stay private, use `connect`
> to only connect to "trusted" nodes.
>
> If you run multiple nodes on a LAN, there's no need for all of them to open lots
> of connections.  Instead "connect" them all to one node that is port
> forwarded and has lots of connections.

Further documentation for `addnode` is [here](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.0/rpc/network/addnode/).